# Selecting user with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of users and if you click on a user there has to be create a new message.

But every time I click on a user id is 0

I have this:

action method:

```
public ActionResult StuurBericht(int id = 0, string onderwerp = "")
        {

            using (var rep = new GebruikerRepository(Context.Klant.Id))
            {
                 var model = PersoneelsDossierService.GetPersoneelsDossierMutatieModel(Context.Klant.Id, GetMutatieRol(), int.Parse(Context.Gebruiker.ExternId), Gebruiker.DienstverbandId, Gebruiker.DienstverbandId, "Functionarissen");
                 model.Functionarissen = PersoneelsDossierService.GetFunctionarissen(Context.Klant.Id, Gebruiker.DienstverbandId);

                BeveiligingService.ControleerGebruikerVanKlant(Context.Klant.Id, Context.Gebruiker.Id);

                if (id > 0)
                {
                    ModelState.Clear();

                    var modelMessage = new Message();

                    modelMessage.GebruikerId = id;
                    modelMessage.Onderwerp = string.Format("RE: {0}", onderwerp);

                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

and this is the view:

```
@model List<SDB.Models.Stamtabel>

@{
    var ItemsByAccordatieFunctieGroep = Model.GroupBy(a => a.Code);
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var Accordeerders in ItemsByAccordatieFunctieGroep)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <!-- Default panel contents -->
                    <div class="panel-heading blue">@Accordeerders.Key</div>

                    <!-- List group -->
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        @foreach (var Accordeerder in Accordeerders)
                        {
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("StuurBericht", "PersoneelsDossier")?id=#=data.VerzenderId#&onderwerp=#=data.Onderwerp#">@Accordeerder.Omschrijving</a>


                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

So my question is:

How to return the correct user and that you will get the correct id?

Thank you

this has to be the link for new message:

SelfService/Profiel/Nieuw?id=6240&onderwerp=test

So the controller is: Profiel.

But now the link is this:

/PersoneelsDossier/StuurBericht/0?onderwerp=HRM%20Management

So the controller link is incorrect.

Comment: what is all that `...?id=#=data.VerzenderId#&onderwerp....` stuff?

Comment: That is the link where you can see the user id

Comment: It makes no sense (what are the `#` characters for? and nothing after that character will be sent to the server). You create the `href` attribute using `@Url.Action("StuurBericht", "PersoneelsDossier", new { id = someValue, onderwerp = someValue })`

Comment: but if I do this:  <a href="@Url.Action("StuurBericht", "PersoneelsDossier")">@Accordeerder.Omschrijving</a> I will get a message there is no view created

Comment: What are you talking about? And the code in your comment is not what I stated (your not passing any values to the method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @Url.Action is wrong, it should be:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("StuurBericht", "PersoneelsDossier", new { id = Accordeerder.YOUR_ID, onderwerp = Accordeerder.ANOTHER_PROPERTY })">@Accordeerder.Omschrijving</a>
```